# Not able to access value of variable present inside a script tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the value of a variable present inside a `script` tag. But I am not able to retrieve the value. I tried in few ways but I don't get the expected result.
I need to get the values and parse and do some operations over it but I am blocked from morning can u please some one help me it's ruining my time.

```js
var scriptTag = document.getElementsById('test');
console.log(scriptTag.window["ytInitialData"]); //shows undefined
console.log(scriptTag.getAttribite(window["ytInitialData"])); // shows null
```

```html
<script id="test">
  window["ytInitialData"] = {
    "responseContext": {
      "serviceTrackingParams": [{
        "service": "GFEEDBACK"
      }]
    }
  };
  window["ytInitialPlayerResponse"] = {
    "responseContext": {
      "serviceTrackingParams": [{
        "service": "GFEEDBACK"
      }]
    }
  };
  if (window.ytcsi) {
    window.ytcsi.tick("pdr", null, '');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're referencing it as `window["ytInitialData"]` in your script.  So reference it as `window["ytInitialData"]` everywhere.  Window is global.  You don't need to get the script tag at all.

Comment: Also it's `getElementById()`, not `getElementsById()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `window` object is global and can be accessed from any script on your page, so set the window property like this:

```
window.ytInitialData = {
    "responseContext": {
      "serviceTrackingParams": [{
        "service": "GFEEDBACK"
      }]
   }
}
```

"ytInitialData" is a string literal so you can use dot notation instead of brackets.

Then access it again anywhere later in your script the same way:

```
console.log(window.ytInitialData)
```

```js
window.ytInitialData = {
  "responseContext": {
    "serviceTrackingParams": [{
      "service": "GFEEDBACK"
    }]
  }
}

console.log(window.ytInitialData)
```